# Double-quotient space

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Assume we have a topological space $X $ and we have an equivalence relations $R,S $. We have the quotient spaces $(X/R)/S,(X/S)/R,X/(R\cap S) $. Are these spaces homeomorphic?

Note that this question is both set theoretical and topological. That is, is it true "set-wise" and if so, whether the identity is a homeomorphim.

I'm not sure if this question is trivial or does it require a proof using the universal property or so.

Comment: The existence of $(X/R)/S$ requires that $S$ is an equivalence relation on $X/R$ (so not on $X$). Such a relation corresponds with an equivalence relation $T$ on $X$ that has the property that $xRy\implies xTy$. In that case you can define $S$ by stating that $([x]_R,[y]_R)\in S\iff xTy$.

Comment: You're right. In my case, I use identifications and the generated relations of these identifications. Assume I first identify sets by $R $ and then by $S $. Is it the same as doing it in the opposite order, Or simultaneously?

Comment: Do you mean that in case $(X/R)/S$ (where both $R$ and $S$ are relations on $X$) you have quotient functions $x\mapsto[x]_R\mapsto\{y\mid\exists z\in[x]_R[ySz]\}$?

Comment: Indeed. I want to first identify by $R $ And then identify the cosets by $S $ and in the opposite order.

Comment: In general this will not even be defined, in either order. You need to impose some compatibility assumptions on $R$ and $S$.